# TypeError: Cannot find function getActiveSpreadsheet in object Spreadsheet. (line 155, file "Code")

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am working to pull from three source sheets ("src"||"s") compare cells and output complete row into target sheet. I have attached my code for reference below. Any help would be appreciated Thanks!

```
function checkRecord() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('sheet id'),
     activesheet = ss.getActiveSpreadsheet(),
     srctrg0 = ss.getSheetByName("sheet name"),
     srctrg1 = ss.getSheetByName("sheet name"),
     srctrg2 = ss.getSheetByName("sheet name"),
     target1 = ss.getSheetByName("sheet name"),    
     s0Range = srctrg0.getDataRange(), 
     s1Range = srctrg1.getDataRange(), 
     s2Range = srctrg2.getDataRange(),
     tRange = target1.getDataRange(),

     stValues0 = s0Range.getValues(),
     s0 = stValues0.length,

     stValues1 = s1Range.getValues(),
     s1 = stValues1.length,

     stValues2 = s2Range.getValues(),
     s2 = stValues2.length,

     tValues = tRange.getValues(),
     t = tValues.length;

      Logger.log(s0);

  for(i = 0; i < stValues0.length; i++){

      if(true)
      {

      }

   }

}
```

Comment: You don't need this line `activesheet = ss.getActiveSpreadsheet(),`

Comment: Make use of the autocomplete to avoid such errors. Control space in the script editor and you will get all the available methods

Comment: I've removed the ambiguous declaration. I am getting TypeError: Cannot call method "getDataRange" of null. (line 155, file "Code") after verifying the spreadsheet id and existing populated sheets

Comment: Check your sheet names then.  Because its telling you that at least one of your sheets is a null.

Comment: I verified data exists in all of the sheets..AHHHHHHHH I had space in one of the names of the sheets. Everything is working now! Thank you for your help!